# HTML5 Collapsable on multiple containers

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have multiple containers and i need them each to be able to collapse and reopen upon user interaction. Presently, i can only open but when i click on the 'Details' the divs do not close.

I have tried altering the collapse and also adding ids and making the data-target that id but still the same issue

Link:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4OW7SFO0DYR

Comment: id must be unique, and you included the jquery, bootstrap js twice. It is not necessary to include it twice

Comment: I agree with Tamil. No need to call your libraries twice. Take out the second set of calls and it works. See here - https://jsfiddle.net/k1mdyw37/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
    <div class="card" id="card0" style="background-color: #c8c372; border:5px solid black;"><div class="description">
    <h4 style="font-size: 25px; text-align: center"><b> Bottled water | $2 </b></h4><h5 style="text-align: center"></h5>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    button{
    padding-left: 40%;
    padding-right: 45%;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Details</button>
      <div id="demo" class="collapse multi-collapse">
        Brands of water include: Dasani, Nestle, and Fiji
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><span id="next-content0"></span></div>

    ---------------
    ------------------
    ------------

    <div class="card" id="card0" style="background-color: #c8c372; border:5px solid black;"><div class="description">
    <h4 style="font-size: 25px; text-align: center"><b> Bottled water | $2 </b></h4><h5 style="text-align: center"></h5>
    <div class="container_1">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo_1">Details</button>
      <div id="demo_1" class="collapse multi-collapse">
        Brands of water include: Dasani, Nestle, and Fiji
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><span id="next-content0"></span></div>
```

Please add your CSS and JS in the head tag. you don't need to call CSS and JS everywhere.

Comment: Question, when i run that code above(in w3 schools) or the one in the jsfiddle, the first 'box' has a space on both the right and left side of the word "Detail" while the second one does not have any spacing. How can i resolve this: 1) Remove spacing from top box 2) add spacing to second box

Comment: Ideally, i would like to see the Button for 'Details' in the middle of the container. Positioned at the middle of the header 'Bottled Water | $2'. Please see the following link with modified changes https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4Q7LP8YVOT4

Comment: @user22418, please replace class 'container_1' with 'container'. It is defined in bootstrap.css

Comment: And if you want all things in the container should be in the center then add class 'text-center' as well. Like <div class="container text-center">